# Get ActionBar Item View to animate it

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation, android-view

My application is basically an online store that has a cart. The button to start the cart is in the ActionBar. When someone presses on a product it starts an animation where the product quicly "slides" through the screen towards the ActionBar cart button. As soon as that finishes the cart "blinks". To blink the cart I use

```
ValueAnimator cartAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCartItem, "alpha", 1,
                0.25f, 0);
```

Where mCartItem is the ActionBar Item View to be animated.

Now as it turns out getting the View of the actual ActionBar item is kinda hard. I can get the View in onOptionsItemSelected but that's basically it, however this won't work for me since the animation isn't triggered from the ActionBar, it's triggered from a ListView in the main UI. After some googling I did however find a hack around this, that works:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cartmenu, menu);
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mCartItem = findViewById(R.id.theitem);
        }
    });
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

1. Why is this way working? As opposed to:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cartmenu, menu);
       mCartItem = findViewById(R.id.theitem); // Always ends up null.
       return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
   }
   ```
2. How would you solve the problem I had?

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` 
searches for a child view with the given id in "this" view. When you call it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` the menu is still not attached to the main view, so you it cannot find your item.
Using `Handler().post(new Runnable()...)` the `findViewById(R.id.theitem)` is executed after all your view is created and, of course, even the menu has been attached to your main view, so it can be found.

Better solution:

since you are inflating your cart menu in the menu object, you can use:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cartmenu, menu);
    mCartItem = menu.findItem(R.id.theitem); //This will find your menu item! :-)
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Comment: It's not the same you have posted, using `menu.findItem(R.id.theitem);` (that is different from `findViewById(R.id.theitem);`) you avoid creating an unnecessary new hanndler thread, so it's more efficient.